# How to iterate/loop minipage that means execute same minpage with same content?

Tags: minipage, loops

I have the following code where I write same minipage again and again. I want to write this minipage one time with same output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}
%\newfontfamily\englishfont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Linux Biolinum O}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali]{Akaash}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\\

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{2cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\foreach \x in {চাল,ডাল,লবণ,তেল,মরিচ,পেঁয়াজ,রসুন,আদা,মুরগী,মশলা}
{
\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do that is to load the multido package. Then just use

```
\multido{}{# of iterations}{Stuff to iterate}
```

I don't have Bengali fonts installed, but here is a similar example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0cm,top=0.2cm,bottom=0cm,right=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\ListItem}[1]{\underline{\makebox[5cm][l]{#1}}}
\newcommand{\minicontent}{\foreach \x in {first,a,b,c,d,last}{\ListItem{\x}\par\bigskip}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\multido{}{9}{\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}\minicontent\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Which gives:[image]

Comment: @alhelal Yeah, I think it's being picky if there are empty lines in the argument, anyway, you might have to make sure it doesn't enter vmode.

Comment: @alhelal Do I really need to explain the rest? Copy my example, load your fonts, replace the content of the \foreach list with your own and it should work. Also, you should probably be nicer about it. I couldn't care less about your acceptance: I'm doing you a favor here, not the reverse...

Comment: When I put `left=0.1cm` then upper and lower columns are not alligned. https://ibb.co/mLxogo https://ibb.co/iyduMo

Comment: Now it is compiled also in Bengali. Just solve the alignment problem.

Comment: @alhelal It stays aligned for me. Did you remember to put \noindent before the loop? I think they are misaligned in your run because it indents the first line as the start of a paragraph.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the same content to be repeated, put it into a `\savebox`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newsavebox{\MyBox}
\savebox{\MyBox}{%
    \begin{minipage}{0.30\textwidth}
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. 
        Ut purus elit, vestibu- lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, fe- lis. 
        Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. 
        Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. 
        Donec vehicula augue eu neque.%
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\begin{document}
\noindent
\usebox{\MyBox}\hfill\usebox{\MyBox}\hfill\usebox{\MyBox}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for Bengali. see the code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2H2mRZ6DX9/ and image here https://pasteboard.co/HdjhnuM.png